# random variables about birthdays

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expectation

So lets do away with months/days and assume everyone has a birthday $X_k$ which corresponds to a number from $1$ to $365$, uniformly distributed

In a group of $n$ people, let $M=\max (X_k)$ be the last birthday of the year and let $N=|\{X_1,X_2,\dots, X_n\}|$ be the number of distinct birthdays.

Now it seems obvious that $E[M]\approx \frac{365n}{n+1}$ and maybe $E[M^2] \approx \frac{365^2n}{n+2}$ by approximating as a uniform r.v.

As for $N$, we could get $E[N]=n\left(1-\left(\frac{364}{365}\right)^n\right)$, and maybe $E[N^2]$ by a similar argument to the elevator question...

My real question is: can we find a way to calculate $E[MN]$? Since $M$ and $N$ are dependent, I cannot find a nice way to express their joint distribution and therefore this expectation escapes me

Comment: even if i can determine how $E[MN]$ depends on $n$ that would be great, like if it grows linearly, grows/decays exponentially, etc. I cannot intuitively see which